# Task does not contain of definition of Select

Tags: c#

I am making the async httpclient call as follows.

```
var myDataDtos = new GetAvailableCoursesCommand()
            .SetUserId(Id)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

I am getting an error on `.Select()` part. It says `Task` does not contain of definition of `Select`

```
var yourData = new List<string>(myDataDtos.Select(x => x.Id.ToString()));
```

HttpClient methods are follow:

```
public async override Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    await _httpService.GetAsync(Url, _parameters, SuccessAction, ErrorAction);
}

public async Task GetAsync<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, Action<T> successAction,
        Action<Exception> errorAction = null)
        where T : class
{
        await GoRequestAsync(url, parameters, HttpMethod.Get, successAction, errorAction);
}

 private static async Task GoRequestAsync<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, HttpMethod method,
            Action<T> successAction, Action<Exception> errorAction = null, string body = "")
            where T : class
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()))
            {
               await GoRequest(httpClient, request,
                    response =>
                    {
                        if (successAction == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            var result = typeof (T) == typeof (string)
                                ? response as T
                                : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
                            successAction(result);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if (errorAction != null)
                            {
                                errorAction(ex);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    error =>
                    {
                        if (errorAction != null)
                        {
                            errorAction(error);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

when this code runs

```
var myDataDtos = new GetAvailableCoursesCommand()
            .SetUserId(Id)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

you get an object of type Task, which as the compiler is saying does not have a definition for .Select

You need to await the task to actually get the result. Something like this

```
var myDataDtos = await (new GetAvailableCoursesCommand()
            .SetUserId(Id)
            .ExecuteAsync());
```

Comment: I am getting the following error `await` does not exist in the current context

Comment: There does need to be an await somewhere, but the answer isn't this simple. The OP has ExecuteAsync returning Task so there needs to be a deeper change than just adding an await there.

Comment: `ExecuteAsync` returns `Task`, so that won't actually help too much

Comment: @mikez ... and since it's an `override`, a much deeper change is needed

Comment: @mikez any guidance?

Comment: @camilo any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem starts here:

```
public async override Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    await _httpService.GetAsync(Url, _parameters, SuccessAction, ErrorAction);
}
```

What's the point of executing a `GET` if you will not be able to return the data to the caller?
You have two options:

1. If you are the owner of the base class (whoever is declaring `ExecuteAsync`):

   ```
   public async override Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>()
   {
       return await _httpService.GetAsync(Url, _parameters, SuccessAction, ErrorAction);
   }
   ```
2. If you are not the owner of that class or you cannot change it (due to the method coming from an interface, for example), you will need to skip the call to `ExecuteAsync` completely and call `GoAsync` yourself. Since you did not provide any kind of details as to where the data that method uses comes from, I cannot give you an example.

As was already mentioned, whichever approach you use, you still need to change your caller to:

```
var data = new GetAvailableCoursesCommand().SetUserId(Id);
var myDataDtos = await data.ExecuteAsync();
```